# Breaking a stick randomly at two points: Expected value of the largest piece.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation, conditional-expectation

If a stick of unit length is broken randomly at two points, to make 3 pieces of stick. What is the expected value of the largest stick.

Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using $2$ uniformly distributed random variables. Then the lengths are given by $X$, $Y-X$ and $1-Y$ (assuming $X<Y$). There might be a simpler model, I'll revisit later.

Comment: Similar question was answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/14190/99255