# Distribution of the largest interval when partitioning [0,1] into n intervals with n-1 uniformly distributed points.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $\lbrace x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1}\rbrace$ be n-1 points that are independently uniformly distributed on interval [0,1]. They create n segments. What is the expected length of the largest of such n segments? What is the distribution?

A good if not complete solution here.
[Average length of the longest segment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/average-length-of-the-longest-segment/14194#14194)

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162560/distribution-of-the-largest-fragment-of-a-broken-stick-spacings This should be an excellent source