# Geometry and PDF around the unit stick broken into 3 pieces and the expected length of the longest piece?

Tags: probability, geometry

This post is related to previous SE posts, could anyone please explain the final geometry steps i.e. the link between the geometry and the pdf.

- [Average length of the longest segment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/average-length-of-the-longest-segment]) : **this part** : " By rewriting this probability as area in the unit square, I get " @TCL.

@TCL gave a very clear explanation for almost the same problem with : [If a 1 meter rope is cut at two uniformly randomly chosen points, what is the average length of the smallest piece?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13959/if-a-1-meter-rope-is-cut-at-two-uniformly-randomly-chosen-points-what-is-the-av])
but could you please explain **this part** : " which is (1−3a)2(1−3a)2. Note that for these sets to be nonempty, one must have 0≤a≤1/3 0≤a≤1/3 "

- [Stick of unit length is broken into three random pieces, what is the expected length of the longest piece?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093434/stick-of-unit-length-is-broken-into-three-random-pieces-what-is-the-expected-le]) : **this part** : " A bit of geometry will give you the result  " @Canardini

Another very quick reply to a very similar problem : @ Hans Parshall

- [If a 1 meter rope is cut at two uniformly randomly chosen points, what is the average length of the smallest piece?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13959/if-a-1-meter-rope-is-cut-at-two-uniformly-randomly-chosen-points-what-is-the-av])" **This part :** It's not hard to show that they all have probability ... / our joint PDF is given by f(x,y)=6f(x,y)=6"

Answer (score 0):

I will be using this: [Stick of unit length is broken into three random pieces, what is the expected length of the longest piece?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093434/stick-of-unit-length-is-broken-into-three-random-pieces-what-is-the-expected-le]).

Right before the "A bit of geometry will give you the result", the answer there had the joint probability $$2P(X\leq a,1-Y\leq a,Y-X\leq a,X<Y).$$ In order to solve that joint probability, we need to find out the situations in which all four probabilities are true at the same time. Now, $$X\leq a,1-Y\leq a,Y-X\leq a,X<Y$$ are also a system of inequalities of variables $X$ and $Y$, and thus can be plotted on a plane with lines as boundaries. The area enclosed by the four inequalities as well as the bounding unit square is the joint probability for any particular $a$.

If n cuts are made, instead of 2, then the inequalities will be of n different variables, in dimension n bounded by hyper-planes of dimension n-1 instead, and you are to find the hyper-volume enclosed.