# How to show geometrically the CDF of the stick problem (with three pieces)?

Tags: probability, geometry, random-variables

I have come across this classic probability problem and I cannot wrap my head around how this CDF was constructed geometrically.

Can anyone show how we can find the area of P using unit square please?

The original problem is described here, however there are no details provided for this step: [Average length of the longest segment.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/average-length-of-the-longest-segment%5D)

And here: [Stick of unit length is broken into three random pieces, what is the expected length of the longest piece?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093434/stick-of-unit-length-is-broken-into-three-random-pieces-what-is-the-expected-le%5D) This part : " A bit of geometry will give you the result " @Canardini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Image of answer]

$$<a>=\int_{1/3}^{1/2} (18a-6)a\, da+\int_{1/2}^{1} (6-6a)a\, da=$$
$$=(6a^3-3a^2)|_{1/3}^{1/2}+(3a^2-2a^3)|_{1/2}^{1}=$$
$$=(6/8-3/4)-(6/27-3/9)+(3-2)-(3/4-2/8)=11/18$$

Comment: $P(1/3<a<1/2)$ is not probability of $1/3<a<1/2$ is probability of longest segment to be less than $a$ at certain $a$ in this interval.

Comment: Thank you so much for this reponse. I now can see it!