# Dividing a rope into three random pieces. Expected longest length

Tags: probability

A rope of 1m is divided into three pieces by two random points. Find the average length of the largest segment.

This question has been answered here:
[Average length of the longest segment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/average-length-of-the-longest-segment)

Someone had a solution:

let the cuts be at $X, Y$, with $Y \gt X$:

[Image of cut positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9jBf.png)

Then each piece is equally likely to be the longest, and the expected length of the longest piece doesn't depend on which piece we choose. Then we can calculate $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(X|X \text{ is the longest piece} )$.

We have the three inequalities:
$$X \gt Y-X \implies Y < 2X$$
$$X \gt 1-Y \implies Y > 1-X$$
and, from our setup,
$$Y \gt X$$
These can be represented by the following diagram:

[Diagram of inequalities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txw6B.png)

Then the area satisfying our inequalities is the two triangles A and B. So we wish to find the expected value of $X$ within this area.

The expected value of $X$ in A is $\bar{X}_A = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{8}{18}$.

The expected value of $X$ in B is $\bar{X}_B = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{4}{6} = \frac{12}{18}$

The area of A is $A_A = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}\times (\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{1}{24}$.

The area of B is $A_B = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8} = \frac{3}{24} = 3 A_A$.

So $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(X|X \text{ is the longest piece} ) = \frac{\tfrac{8}{18} + 3\left(\tfrac{12}{18}\right)}{4} = \frac{11}{18}$

I understand everything but I got lost when he said calculate expected value of $X$ within triangles. How do you exactly find the expected value of $X$ over the triangle $A$ and $B$? How did he come up with $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(X|X \text{ is the longest piece} )$?

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is a linear function on each triangle. The average value of a linear function on a triangle is the average of its values at the three vertices.

Answer (score 0):

In your problem, $\bar{X}_A$ is the $x$-coordinate of triangle A's center. To calculate it, use that the center of a triangle is situated at $1/3$ of any edge center.