# A rope of 1m is divided into three pieces by two random points. Find the average length of the largest segment... with an algorithm!

Tags: probability, probability-theory

About the title, I've read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452753/expected-length-of-longest-piece-when-a-stick-is-broken-into-three-pieces) that the answer is 11/18.

I've tried with a simple algorithm:

```
def cut(first_len:int) -> List[Union[float,float]]:
    c1 = random.uniform(0,first_len)
    return [c1, first_len-c1]


if __name__=='__main__':
    max_val = 0

    num_iter = 1000000
    m_len = 1
    for _ in range(num_iter):
        #first random cut
        cut_vals = cut(m_len)

        # second random cut on the longest piece
        max_cut2_vals = cut(max(cut_vals))

        # get the max
        m2 = max(max_cut2_vals)

        max_val = max_val+m2
    
    print(max_val/num_iter)
```

that returns 0.563, which is a bit lower than 11/18.
I assume that I'm missing some fundamental property.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Not sure anyone will try to debug your code...the duplicate question speaks for itself.

Comment: Why must the second random cut be on the longest piece? The second cut should have a `min(cut_vals)` probability to be on the shorter piece.

Comment: @peterwhy is correct here. Picking two random cut points is not the same as picking one random cut point and then picking a second cut point on the longer of the two pieces. The latter method favors getting three similar-size pieces more often than it ought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rope is divided into three pieces simultaneously: you pick two random real numbers $x, y$ from the $(0, 1)$ interval and then pick the longest piece: either from $0$ to $x$ (which has length $x$), from $x$ to $y$ (which has length $y-x$) or from $y$ to $1$ (which has length $1 - y$). This is assuming that $0 \le x \le y \le 1$ which we can simulate easily in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from random import random
from statistics import mean

def two_cuts():
    x, y = random(), random()
    if x > y
        x, y = y, x # to make sure that 0 <= x <= y <= 1
    return (x, y)

def longest(x, y):
    return max(x, 1-y, y-x)

print(mean([longest(*two_cuts()) for _ in range(10**5)]))
```

I've got $0.611285852578838 \approx 0.611111111111111 \ldots = 11/18$. Everything agrees.

Comment: Yes, you're right. 
The question is picking the two numbers simultaneously (and not as a choice as I did before).

Thank you!