# Probability question: What is the probability that the top-left vertex of the square is within the longest segment?

Tags: probability

There is a rope that can be used to form a square with a side length of 1. Three points are randomly selected on the rope, and the longest segment is chosen. What is the probability that the top-left vertex of the square is in that segment? (We may assume that we start at the top left and work clockwise).

My attempt solution:

Assume the three segment points are A B C. The four vertices are EFGH. The length of the longest segment is $x$.

W.L.O.G, let line AB be the longest segment. Therefore, $|AB|\geq 1/3$.

Our goal is to solve the following objective:
$\int^1_{x=\frac{1}{3}} p(\text{top-left vertex is in longest segment} |x)p(x)dx$

(1) When $1/2>|AB|\geq 1/3$, there are must be one vertex lies in |AB|. The probability is $\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{x=\frac{1}{3}} p(\text{top-left vertex is in longest segment} |x)p(x)dx=\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})}{\frac{2}{3}}$.

(2)When $3/4>|AB|\geq 1/2$, there are must be two vertices lies in |AB|. the probability are $\int^{\frac{3}{4}}_{x=\frac{1}{2}} p(\text{top-left vertex is in longest segment} |x)p(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{2})}{\frac{2}{3}}$

(2)When $|AB|\geq 3/4$, there are must be three vertices lies in |AB|.
the probability are $\int^{1}_{x=\frac{3}{4}} p(x)p(\text{top-left vertex is in longest segment} |x)dx=\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{(1-\frac{3}{4})}{\frac{2}{3}}$.

Sum them together and we get the final result.

Is my answer correct?

Or is there a simpler method to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The question is not very clear. How do you arrange the rope into a square? Do you start at the top left and work clockwise? Or is there some other rule? Can you arrange it however you like?

Comment: @Blitzer Yes, we may start at the top left and work clock-wise. In fact, the four vertices seem to be symmetrical. This means that no matter which vertex we start from or which direction we follow, we should have at the same result.

Comment: The related question [Average length of the longest segment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/average-length-of-the-longest-segment?rq=1) provides the answer.